# Pythonic way to reduce the number of small subclasses in a base class?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I find myself writing many small subclasses for predefined objects.  However, each subclass I create contains a lot of duplicate code (for the base class instantiation).  Essentially, I am using subclasses to store default initialization attributes, specific to the subclass, and common to the base class.

Is using many small subclasses with only an **init**() an acceptable use of subclasses?

For example:
I create a module that contains the base class and subclasses (I have 30 subclasses with slightly different arguments and default arguments).

```
#animals.py
#Contains animal definitions and methods
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, weight, cute=False, kind=None, image=None):
        #Instantiation attributes
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.cute = cute
        self.kind = kind
        self.image = image
        #Attributes common to all animals
        self.extinct = False

    def get_animal_stats(self):
        print arbitrary_animal_stat

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, weight, kind="Mixed Breed"):
        Animal.__init__(self, name, weight, cute=True, kind=kind, image="dog.com")

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        Animal.__init__(self, name, weight, cute=True, image="cat.com")
```

And create instances in other modules through the general Animal class or the more specific, predifined Animal subclasses (tab completion is essential so I can reference specific animal subclasses).

```
import animals    #Uses animal definitions from animals.py

my_animals = [
    animals.Animal("Python", 2.7, cute=False),
    animals.Dog("Snoopy", 60, kind="Cartoon"),
    animals.Cat("Tigger", 50, kind="Tiger"),]

for animal in my_animals:
    animal.get_animal_stats()
```

### I find using a base class with many predefined subclasses creates more explicit code, and allows future expansion.  Still, this creates a lot of duplicate code and I currently have no unique methods for subclasses. It feels like an incorrect use of classing?

I have tried using variables to replace subclass definitions.  This is troublesome if I want to modify anything because I have to remember the defaults and their order, and seems less explicit than subclassing.

```
#Use of variables instead of subclasses
dog = ("True", "Mixed Breed", "dog.com")

Animal("default dog", 60, *animals.dog)
Animal("special dog", 60, cute=False, kind="Guard Dog", image=animals.dog[2])
```

---

Dictionaries are nearly as troublesome because there is as much duplicate code in their definition as the equivalent subclass and it appears less explicit than the more robust subclass counterpart.

```
#Use of dictionaries instead of subclasses
dog = {"cute": True, "kind": "Mixed Breed", "image": "dog.com"}

Animal("default dog", 60, **animals.dog)
Animal("special dog", 60, cute=False, kind="Guard Dog", image=animals.dog["image"])
```

Should I reconsider using subclasses in this context?  If so, what is the Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Should I consider @classmethod or @staticmethod ?  I understand what they do in theory but dont know how/when to implement them.

---

### Additional Questions:

Thank you all for your answers.  I have read them multiple times before responding and have posed slightly modified examples to clarify concepts that still elude me.  I am new to StackOverflow and responded in this way so that I could elaborate more.  If this is an improper use of 'edit', let me know how to proceed.

-I take it that you feel subclassing is acceptable in this context?

-I liked your class variable technique.  I plan to implement that.

-I think your use of **kwargs holds promise but without referencing the source animals.py', how do you know what key-value pairs are valid in the parent class as I initialize the subclass?  They arent available in context when instatiating the subclass.

-I considered defining a default set of **kwargs for each subclass, similar to your class variable technique.  However, I dont entirely understand what happens if I over ride a key-value and then input **kwargs (where the same key is defined in **kwargs).

```
class Dog(Animal):
    WOOF, YAP, HUSH = 'woof', 'yap', 'hush_puppy'
    kwargs = {cute: True, kind: "Generic", image_path: "dog.com"}
    def __init__(self, name, weight, bark=WOOF, **kwargs):
        self.bark = bark
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, weight, **kwargs)


dog1 = Dog("Snoopy", 60, **Dog.kwargs)
dog2 = Dog("Otis", 30, bark=Dog.YAP, cute=False, **Dog.kwargs)
```

Is this valid syntax?  Will the cute=True in Dog.kwargs over ride me setting cute=False in instantiation?

Interesting perspective about taxonomy.  Fortunately, I do have a finite number of subclasses (I dont need to keep specializing), and for my use, it is acceptable that creating a Dog through the Animal base class is not type(Dog).

With this in mind, any other concepts to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would  use super and **kwargs and  add any specific attribute that relates only to that subclass.

```
class Dog(Animal):
    WOOF, YAP, HUSH = 'woof', 'yap', 'hush_puppy'
    def __init__(self, name, weight, bark=WOOF, **kwargs):
        self.bark = bark
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, weight, **kwargs)

class Cat(Animal):
    HAIR_LONG, HAIR_SHORT = 'long', 'short'
    def __init__(self, name, weight,hair=HAIR_LONG, **kwargs):
        self.hair = hair
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name, weight, **kwargs)

dog = Dog("Snoopy", 60, bark=Dog.HUSH)
cat = Cat("Tigger", 50, kind="Tiger",hair=Cat.HAIR_SHORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this, it doesn't create subclasses to define all of your animals, but it does provide a way to define them with far less code than subclassing. Since you are creating instances of your subclasses in other modules anyway, in which you specify features for instantiation, it might work out doing it this way. I am using [**kwargs](http://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)

You have just the Animal base class, and you simply create instances of it, named appropriately, and filled with defining attributes(which it appears you do in those other modules in any case?).

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.features = {k:v for k, v in kwargs.items()}
```

Create a dog:

```
>>> dog = Animal(name="Rover", kind="mixed breed", weight="10kg")
>>> print dog.features['name']
Rover
>>> print dog.features['kind']
mixed breed
```

Or a cat:

```
 >>> cat = Animal(name="Shredder", kind="tabby", cute="True")
 >>> print cat.features['name']
 Shredder
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing egregiously wrong with the way you're specializing your Animal base class, but you are using a taxonomic system (Python classes and inheritance) designed for a small amount of pragmatic categorization (related to implementing code behaviors) and stretching it into an ontologic classification system/taxonomy.

That means there's going to be some rough points, and some occasional idiosyncrasies / counterintuitive results / breakage. For example, if you can instantiate Fido as `Animal` rather than `Dog`, then you won't be able to use this structure to reason about Fido. `isinstnace(fido, Dog)` would answer `False`, even though Fido is a dog. Python just doesn't have a rich enough taxonomic structure to closely represent the variations found in nature. Most languages don't, though some like [CLOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) or [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) might start to approach it.

This is not the first time such a problem has arisen. [This recent question on programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253612/one-boilerplate-class-or-many-similar-classes/255875#255875) is just one of many related class hierarchy challenges discussed on stackoverflow's more theory-of-proggraming sister site.

---

The second issue here is about simple, concise value-setting, not the relative weakness of Python class taxonomies. Your question and some of the answers go through various options: Having custom `__init__` methods in each subclass, using a pure kwarg style of setting, class-based quasi-enumerateds, etc. They all have virtues and drawbacks. When I have faced similar problems, a delegation-based model has proven helpful. Rather than recapitulate it here, [this is the relevant Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703813/240490), and here is the configuration package that implements it: [options](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/options).